# Unable to override views-view-unformatted.tpl.php

Tags: views, theming

I have a view page named `latest` and try to override the template `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` by creating below templates in the theme folder

`views-view-unformatted--latest.tpl.php`
`views-view-unformatted--latest--page.tpl.php`
`views-view-unformatted--page.tpl.php`
`views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`

but none of them works. I clear the caches, rescan template files. I use views 3 and Drupal 7.23.

Can anyone please help me override this template `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`

Comment: quick glance suggests that the names are correct, are the permissions as well?  eg, are you creating them so that your web server can read them?

Comment: I can override other views' default templates. Only the Style Output template is unable to override.

Comment: d'oh.  I ***think*** you need to be trying `views-view-unformatted...`, eg, only one dash before `unformatted`.  Check the suggestions via the Views UI to confirm.

Comment: I have edited the question. It should be only one dash brfore `unformatted`.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Advanced" section of the views configuration, click in "Theme:informaction" and you will see all the possible templates

Regards

Comment: I have give above in my question the possible template names from "Theme:information" and tried by creating them one by one in my theme folder but none of them works.

Comment: You can try clicking on "rescan templates" in "Theme:information" in this way you can see if it is recognizing your template, saving the view and clearing caches.

Comment: I have clear the caches, rescan template files as I mention in my question but doing those doesn't pick the template from my theme folder.